# iOS - Location of a TextField created programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa

I have a doubt: it is wrong to create a TextField from the code and not from interface builder?

For example, I am using 'AwsomeTextField' taken by CocoaPods.

In the pages of explanation says:

```
  let field = AwsomeTextField(frame: CGRect(x: 60, y: 200, width: 320, height: 44))
  field.placeholder = "test"
  view.addSubview(field)
```

But if I assign an absolute position with `CGRect (x: 60, y: 200, width: 320, height: 44)` then if I run the app on an iPad or an iPhone IF of course the graphics becomes atrocious.

I can use the modules of **cocoa pod** from interface builder to add the right constraints, or can I work on autolayout also by code? I'm confused!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to stop you adding constraints to a view created in code:

```
let field = AwsomeTextField(frame: .zero) // Create the view with a zero frame
field.placeholder = "test"
field.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false // You should always do this to views you create in code that you want to apply layout constraints to
view.addSubview(field)
// No that you have added field as a subview, you can add constraints to it here.
```

If you want to use Interface Builder, drag a plain UIView from the picker onto your view controller and add any constraints. Then, set the class of the view from UIView to AwesomeTextField

Comment: Yup, I understand, thank you. But if I wanted to use the interface builder rather than program every single item? (Always using some pod)

Answer (score 0):

'AwsomeTextField' Pod is an extension of a UITextField.

Drag a UITextField object in interface builder, make an outlet and switch the outlet type to AwesomeTextField like that:

```
@IBOutlet weak var awesomeTextField: AwsomeTextField!
```

also include `AwsomeTextField` class in *Custom Class* section of the Identity Inspector in xCode.

This way you don't need to create it from code all the time ;]